# Anaconda - Display table output from CSV

Tags: python, csv, anaconda, spyder

I am trying to produce output from .csv file as a table with column headers. I am trying to display as table with frequencies calculated. so far i can calculate frequencies with this code:

```
import pandas
d = pandas.read_csv('gapminder.csv', low_memory=False)
d['urbanrate'] = d['urbanrate'].convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)

print ('Count Urban rate')
c = d.groupby('urbanrate').size()
print (c)

print ('Urban rate percentage')
f = d.groupby('urbanrate').size() * 100/len(d)
print (f)
```

and the output is like:

```
Count Urban rate
urban rate
10.40     1
12.54     1
12.98     1
```

But i would like to have have columns like:

```
 Rate   Count
 10.40      1
 ..         ..
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the column names:

```
f.columns = ['Rate', 'Count']
print(f)
```

prints:

```
 Rate  Count
0  10.40      1
1  12.54      1
2  12.98      1
```

If you don't like to see the index:

```
print(f.to_string(index=False))
```

prints:

```
Rate  Count
 10.40      1
 12.54      1
 12.98      1
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what i wanted.